# how to fix an if function which returns only the else statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm writing a function that should display a specific text in an area depending on the src of an image. This function runs when the mouse is over another image. The same text is always displayed beside the image.

I've tried if-else functions, onmouseover or addEventListener none of those work.

```
<img id="avatar" src="avatar1.jpg" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
<img src="icon.jpg" class='icon' id='icon'>
<p id='description'> specifit text should appear in here <p>
```

```
/* this function changes the source of 'avatar' and it works fine */

const faces = ["avatar1.jpg", "avatar2.jpg"];
const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');

function changeFace() {
    const face = avatar.src.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    const index = faces.indexOf(face);

    avatar.src = faces[(index + 1) % faces.length];
    console.log(avatar.src);
}

var icon = document.getElementById('icon');
icon.addEventListener('click', changeFace);

/* clicking on the 'icon' changes the src of 'avatar' from 'avatar1.jpg' to 'avatar2.jpg' and vice versa. */

/*this function display 'text' in p 'description', it works fine*/

function writeText(text) {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = text
}

/* this is the function that doesn't work */

function changeText() {
    if (avatar.src === "avatar1.jpg") {
        writeText('text number 1');
    } else {
        writeText('text number 2');
    }
}

icon.addEventListener('mouseover', changeText);
```

it returns 'text number 2' regardless of the src of 'avatar'

Comment: Try dropping in `console.log("src is " + avatar.src);` at the beginning of that function so that you'll at least see what the actual value is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change to `if (avatar.getAttribute('src') === "avatar1.jpg")` instead of `avatar.src`

.src returns a fully qualified absolute URL, even if what was in the HTML was a relative URL. getAttribute() returns the exact attribute of the DOM element

```js
/*this funcion changes the source of 'avatar' and it works fine*/

const faces = [ "avatar1.jpg", "avatar2.jpg" ];
const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');

function changeFace() {
  const face = avatar.src.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  const index = faces.indexOf( face );

  avatar.src = faces[ ( index + 1 ) % faces.length ];
  console.log( avatar.src );
}

var icon = document.getElementById('icon');
icon.addEventListener('click', changeFace);

/*clicking on the 'icon' changes the src of 'avatar' from 'avatar1.jpg' to 'avatar2.jpg' and viceversa.*/

/*this function display 'text' in p 'description', it works fine*/

function writeText(text) {
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=text
}

/*this is the funcion that doens't work*/

function changeText() {
console.log(avatar.getAttribute('src'))
if (avatar.getAttribute('src') === "avatar1.jpg") {
writeText('text number 1');}
else { writeText('text number 2');}
}

icon.addEventListener('mouseover', changeText);
```

```html
<img id="avatar" src="avatar1.jpg" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
<img src="icon.jpg" class='icon' id='icon'>
<p id='description'> specifit text should appear in here <p>
```